# QNetworkAccessManager doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I have the following code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    m_networkAccessManager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(m_networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyForGeoCoordinates(QNetworkReply*)));
    getCoordinates();
}

void MainWindow::getCoordinates()
{
    std::string query = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=warsaw&sensor=false&language=en";
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(QString::fromStdString(query)));
    m_reply = m_networkAccessManager->get(request);

    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(rep()));
    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(rep()));
}
```

and I want to send query to the google server and get response, but when I send request none of the above slots don't call, so what am I doing wrong ? If I put that address in my browser I get some data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your mistake in connections. They must be declares *before* you call `get()` function.

Comment: I don't think so, because connect works only on real objects. In your solution I have connect(null, SIGNAL(.....), so it results in an error

Comment: Wait. How you think the reply can emit you anything without any action? You just get it from `get()`, but you do nothing with it to recieve a signal.

Comment: m_networkAccessManager->get() posts me request to the server and get() returns QNetworkReply obj, which emits signal
the same for m_networkAccessManager when network reply will be finished the signal will be emited

Comment: Ok. See the doc: `void QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply * reply)`

_This signal is emitted whenever a pending network reply is finished. The reply parameter will contain a pointer to the reply that has **just finished**. This signal is emitted in tandem with the QNetworkReply::finished() signal._

Comment: Assuming that the rep() and slotError() slots are declared correctly and the connects work (if not, there should be warnings on the console, at least in debug mode), bladzio’s code looks completely correct to me and is the usual way to connect to QNetworkReply objects. (get returns the object, one connects to it, the signals are guaranteed to be emitted later in the event loop)

Comment: Downvoted, you should NOT connect empty objects and you should not connect `QNetworkReply` before a `get()` or `put()`.